# Refresh page on Heroku with Pusher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket, refresh, pusher

I've got an App on Heroku with multiple users, who can bet each other. When a user post a new Bet the Bet should ppear on all other users Home page, so they can take action on it if they want to.

The problem is that I need the Home page to auto refresh when a new Bet is created. I don't want to use the simple HTTP refresh thing, sp I'm thinking on using Pusher, since the App is hosted on Heroku.

But i'm not sure on how to implement this. Could anyone direct me in the right direction - preferably with some code examples.

It seems that all the examples I can find refers to a chat application :)

Comment: When you use Pusher the page doesn't refresh. You are delivered the data over an open WebSocket connection and then you can update the page using that data. The purpose of technologies like this is to remove the need for page refreshes. This is one piece on the puzzle that lets us build rich interactive applications in the web browser.

Comment: Thanks.. But is it then not possible to trigger a new query into the database, which is what I want to do. When a user creates a new Bet, i would like the DIV containing these Bets on the webpage that all clients see to be refreshed (render the partial again with a new query to the database)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout Pusher's getting started [page](http://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start). This should be very straight forward.
I assume you have a `Bet` model. In that case

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :push_notification, :on => :create, :if => :persisted?

  def push_notification
   Pusher["bets"].trigger("created", {:id => id, :message => "New bet created"}.to_json)
  end
end
```

On your views you should be doing,

```
var pusher = new Pusher('abc243231a132b21c321'); // Replace with your app key
var channel = pusher.subscribe('bets');


channel.bind('created', function(data) {
  alert('A new bet was created: ' + data.message);
});
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: That seems to work.. but instead of the Alert I need to refresh a DIV with the ID #tickets. How do I change the above view code to accomplish that?

Comment: I can show you a quick and dirty way of doing it by constructing a raw html in the client side(Browser). But this is not the best way because constructing raw html is not manageable in long run.

`channel.bind('created', function(data) {
  $("#tickets").append("<div>"+ data.message +"</div>");
})`

You can consider rendering this entire html as a part of the json response, in which case you can have a separate view for this message alone.

Comment: I also played around with something similar: `$("#bets").html("<%= escape_javascript render 'shared/active_bets' %>");`. But it doesn't fetch the newly created Bet from the controller. Is it not possible to have the partial rendered from scratch so to speak?

Comment: This won't work. `<%= escape_javascript render 'shared/active_bets' %>`, this will be evaluated when your page loads. So this will evaluate to `$("#bets").html(<div>bets present during the page load</div>);`. You are replacing the same html over and over again. Try constructing the html raw inside your javascript to some thing I like I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this railscasts, it can be adapted to your application.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub